# Use of a categorical variable to define colors and markers in bokeh scatter plot

Tags: python, bokeh, scatter

I have a pandas dataframe with two data columns (for simplicity let us call them 'x' and 'y'), and a categorical column (say 'color' with values 'red', 'green', and 'blue'). Now I want to use bokeh to generate a scatter plot with different marker symbols ('red'->'x', 'green'->'o', and 'blue'->'triangle').

While I did find a solution where I extracted the relevant portions of 'x' and 'y' values manually, I thought it should be possible to do this in one command using "categorical" plotting in bokeh. However, the documentation primarily considers bar plots, and when I try to use the result of df.groupby('color') in ColumnDataSource, plotting 'x' and 'y' in scatter (with source=source) fails, because the column names 'x' and 'y' are not found.

Here is a sample code to illustrate the problem:

```
import pandas as pd
import bokeh.plotting as plt

df = pd.DataFrame(data=[[0., 0., 'red'], [1., 0., 'red'], [1., 1., 'green'],
                        [1., 2., 'blue'], [2., 1., 'blue']],
                  columns=['x', 'y', 'color'])
source = plt.ColumnDataSource(df.groupby('color'))
# source = plt.ColumnDataSource(df) -- this would work for colors
fig = plt.figure()
fig.scatter('x', 'y', color='color', source=source)
plt.show(fig)
```

This snippet presents the minimum needed. Without the groupby, color='color' actually works, but in my real example, the categorical variable has non-color values. Furthermore, how would I specify multiple symbols as requested?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UPDATE: The original answer below is still valid, but this kind of thing can now also be accomplished more easily with color and marker mapping transforms:

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show
from bokeh.sampledata.iris import flowers
from bokeh.transform import factor_cmap, factor_mark

SPECIES = ['setosa', 'versicolor', 'virginica']
MARKERS = ['hex', 'circle_x', 'triangle']

p = figure(title = "Iris Morphology")
p.xaxis.axis_label = 'Petal Length'
p.yaxis.axis_label = 'Sepal Width'

p.scatter("petal_length", "sepal_width", source=flowers, legend_field="species", fill_alpha=0.4, size=12,
          marker=factor_mark('species', MARKERS, SPECIES),
          color=factor_cmap('species', 'Category10_3', SPECIES))

show(p)
```

[image]

---

*Original Answer*

Passing a `GroupBy` to the CDS is not going to be helpful for you, because that creates a CDS of the *summarize data*, but you want all the individual points. Here is one way to accomplish what you are asking using `CDSView`  and `GroupFilter` as described in [Providing Data for Plots and Tables](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/data.html#):

```
import pandas as pd

from bokeh.io import show
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, CDSView, GroupFilter
from bokeh.plotting import figure


df = pd.DataFrame(data=[[0., 0., 'red'], [1., 0., 'red'], [1., 1., 'green'],
                        [1., 2., 'blue'], [2., 1., 'blue']],
                  columns=['x', 'y', 'color'])

source = ColumnDataSource(df)

# create views for the different groups
red = CDSView(source=source, filters=[GroupFilter(column_name='color', group='red')])
green = CDSView(source=source, filters=[GroupFilter(column_name='color', group='green')])
blue = CDSView(source=source, filters=[GroupFilter(column_name='color', group='blue')])

p = figure()

# use the views with different glyphs
p.circle('x', 'y', size=15, color='red', source=source, view=red)
p.square('x', 'y', size=15, color='green', source=source, view=green)
p.triangle('x', 'y', size=15, color='blue', source=source, view=blue)

show(p)
```

[image: plot of grouped data]

Looking at that it seems like there are some pretty simple and easy improvements that could be made to reduce the amount of code (e.g. maybe a `source.group` methods to do all the work those `CDSView` lines do, or maybe arguments to the glyph methods to specify groups). I'd encourage you to submit a [GitHub feature request issue](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues) to discuss it further.

Comment: Worth mentioning: `color='color'` would still work here, because there is 
a color column. But presumably in real world situations you wouldn't be grouping on a color column, so the above code models that more common use case.

Comment: Also worth mentioning, if you don't need different glyphs for the the groups (i.e. all circles but different colors or sizes) then you could also use color mappers and/or `CustomJSTransform` instead of CS views